# Could reducer class not be launched by any chance? Can't see Sytem.out.println statements in the reducer logs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a driver class, mapper class and reducer class. The mapreduce job runs fine. But the desired out is not coming. I have put System.out.println statements in the reducer. I looked at the logs of mapper and reducer. System.out.println statements that I put in mapper can be seen in the logs but println statements in the reducer are not seen in the logs. Could it be possible that reducer is not at all launched?

This is the log fine from reducer.

[image: Reducer Log file]

Comment: I checked with other mapreduce programs that I wrote. The System.out.Println statements that I have written in reducer are shown in the logs. But not for this program. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try checking how many records Map job output after completion.

Comment: Reducer job is running. But for some reason it is not writing any System.out.println statements to the log files. this is weird

Comment: Are you using "yarn logs -applicationId <YOUR APPLICATION id> command to get all your logs"?

Comment: I don't know if this log is called "yarn logs". When we run a mapreduce job, it gives us the hyperlink to see the Map and Reduce logs. That is what I am looking at.

Comment: What does that hyperlink say about Map input and Map output records ?

Comment: How can I add reducer class code to this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this question is based on the code in your earlier question: [mapreduce composite Key sample - doesn't show the desired output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910096/mapreduce-composite-key-sample-doesnt-show-the-desired-output)

```
public  class CompositeKeyReducer extends Reducer<Country, IntWritable, Country, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Country key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    }
}
```

The reduce isn't running because the `reduce` method signature is wrong. You have:

`public void reduce(Country key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, Context context)`

It should be:

`public void reduce(Country key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)`

To make sure this doesn't happen again you should add the `@Override` annotation to the class. This will tell you if you've got the signature wrong.

Comment: Got it. Let me try and will let you know.

Comment: I changed from "Iterator" to "Iterable" in reduce parameter. Created the Jar and ran the program. still no change in the output. The thing is I don't even see the comments I put in reducer (sytem.out.println). This is very weird. Do you want to see my driver code as well? How can I post the code in "Comment" box? Thanks much

Comment: Is does the output look like `part-r-00000` or `part-m-00000`? In the counters for the job can you see the counts for the reduce stage?

Comment: Yes the output looks like part-r-00000. I will check on counters and let you know. I am also going to make number of reduers to zero and see if it  makes any difference in the output

Comment: Did you add the `@Override` annotation to your code? If the counters tell you a reduce stage ran, its likely it just ran the identity reducer in the base `Reducer` class you're extending.

Comment: Got it Binary Nerd. I will check in the evening and will let you know.

Comment: I did add @Override annotation to the reduce method in the reducer. No change in the output. It say map.reduce.job counters=49. In the reduce method, I put System.out.println statment. For some reason, the print statement doesn't get executed and it doesn't show in the logs.

Comment: Counters are your friend. They will tell you how many keys and values were processed. You're getting `part-r` files which means a reduce has run. Instead of using print statements, you should just add a custom counter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115411/discussion-between-basam-and-binary-nerd).

Answer (score 0):

No change in the code. It works now. 
All I did was restarted my Hadoop Cloudera image and it works now. I can't believe this happended.